# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 limitations

Tags: database-performance, sql-server-2008-r2

When considering to use an Express Edition of SQL Server 2008 for a system that officially is only tested with full editions, what do I need to know about the limitations?

Memory, connections? What about backup and restore features? Can I set up automatic backups of certain databases on the Express edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looks like you want this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.ASPX).

Basically, you're limited to 1 CPU, 1 GB RAM usage, 10 GB database size, no high-availability options, and the bare-bones basics in every other category.

(Regarding the backups, I believe it's doable, but you'll [probably] have to use the SQL Management Studio provided with a proper SQL edition to set those up.)

Comment: And the SQL Agent doesn't start.

Comment: I've gotten around the no SQL Agent for backups thing with scripts that invoke sqlcmd that are kicked off by task scheduler.  So it's doable, but it's not built in.